# Finding a missing subset into a set

Tags: sql, postgresql, set

I have 3 tables:

```
cert         sct           server
========    =========    ============
cert_id     cert_id        serv_id
pem         serv_id        url
date_added  load           
type
```

Basically, every time I get a new certificate (table `cert`), I will submit it to different servers(in table `server` for timestamping, and save the response in table `sct`. For some reason, I may have some certificates that were not submitted.

Also, only certificates of type `sign` can be submitted.
So I need to resubmit them.

For that, I need to find certificates that have not been submitted to specific servers.

```
cert
======
cert_id       pem      date_added      type
--------------------------------------------
idCert1      (data)      (date)        sign
idCert2      (data)      (date)        email
idCert3      (data)      (date)        sign
idCert4      (data)      (date)        sign
idCert5      (data)      (date)        email


sct
====
cert_id        serv_id         load
------------------------------------
idCert1        serv1           (data)
idCert1        serv2           (data)
idCert3        serv1           (data)

server
======
serv_id       url
--------------------
serv1         url1
serv2         url2
```

Assuming these records, I want this results:

```
cert_id     pem      serv_id         url
-----------------------------------------
idCert3     (data)   serv2           URL2
idCert4     (data)   serv1           URL1
idCert4     (data)   serv2           URL2
```

So far, the best I could do was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cert 
WHERE type='sign' 
AND cert_id NOT IN (SELECT cert_id 
                    FROM sct 
                    GROUP BY cert_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(cert_id)>=nbr_srv );
```

where `nbr_srv` is the total number of servers in table `server`. That query only gives me certificates that haven't been submitted to all servers. 
I don't know if it is possible to get what I want with a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70b38924f1c52df80728200002fc5daa)

Generate CROSS JOIN over all possible server/cert combinations and remove the real exisiting combinations:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cert c
CROSS JOIN serv s
WHERE c.type = 'sign' AND (c.id, s.id) NOT IN (
    SELECT
        cert_id, serv_id
    FROM
        sct sc
)
```